# How to get and use value length of associated array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Now I am trying to get length of value in an associated array like below.

In the final, I would like to change styles for each value.

Do someone know how to solve this?

```
const shopLists = [
  { genre: 'aaa', image: AAA},
  { genre: 'bb' , image: BBB},
  { genre: 'ccc', image: CCC},
  { genre: 'ddddd', image: DDD}
]

//
<Text style={ styles.shopListsGenre }>
  {shopLists.genre}
</Text>

///

//I would like to apply 33% padding to aaa and ccc genre and apply
  other padding to others.

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 shopListsGenre: {
  paddingLeft: '33%'
 },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do. Do you mean this?

```
const shopLists = [
  { genre: 'aaa', image: AAA},
  { genre: 'bb' , image: BBB},
  { genre: 'ccc', image: CCC},
  { genre: 'ddddd', image: DDD}
]

const items = shopLists.map(item => {
  <Text style={item.genre === 'aaa' || item.genre === 'ccc' ? styles.shopListsGenre : styles.customStyle}>
    {item.genre}
  </Text>
});

{items}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 shopListsGenre: {
  paddingLeft: '33%'
 },
})
```